# Can spring handle indirect dependency injection?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

I am currently trying to understand the way in which spring creates and destroys beans and how it comes up with the right order to do so.
Lets assume we have three classes

```
@Component
class Demo1 {

}
```

```
@Component
class Demo2{

   Demo1 demo1;
   
   // specifically not using @Autowired
   public Demo2(Demo1 demo1){
      this.demo1 = demo1;
   }

   public Demo1 getDemo1(){
     return this.demo1
   }
}
```

```
@Component
class Demo3 {
   
   Demo1 demo1
   Demo2 demo2;

   public Demo3(Demo1 demo1, Demo2 demo2){
     this.demo1 = demo1;
     this.demo2 = demo2;
   }
}
```

Config class

```
@Configuration
class MyConfig {

  @Bean
  public Demo1 demo1(){
    return new demo1()
  }

  @Bean
  public Demo2 demo2(){
    return new Demo2(demo1());
  }

  @Bean
  public Demo3 demo3(){
   Demo2 demo2 = demo2()
   return new Demo3(demo2.getDemo1(), demo2);
  }
}
```

I understand that this is not the best/right way to do it but I want to know if its equivalent to using `@Autowired` annotation and if spring is able to resolve the dependency among the beans while creation, that is create in order

1. demo1
2. demo2
3. demo3

and destroy in order

1. demo3
2. demo2
3. demo1

Does changing the order of the functions in `MyConfig` make any difference ?

Currently I am facing an error where I believe `demo1` is getting destroyed before `demo2` or `demo3`

Comment: 1) Spring figures it out as long as you don't have circular dependencies. 2) Order in MyConfig doesn't mater. 3) How do you know about the destroy issue? Any log to look at? 4) Don't annotate with `@Component` AND create `@Beans` in `@Configuration`. This is just doubling up ;)

Comment: I think you could have two problems with this, first one, as other say, you mustn't have circular dependencies, and the second problem its, you can't control the way to destroy or create a bean if not a Singleton, if you want create and destroy in a specific order use the annotation of DependsOn https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-factory-dependson

Comment: I think the default scope is singleton right? and above code does not have a circular dependency

Comment: Mainly I want to know if this equivalent to using constructor injection/ setter injection

Comment: There is no difference. The only ugly or wrong is the `demo2.getDemo1()` and inject that, but as `Demo3` depends on `Demo2` which in turn depends on `Demo1` it doesn't matter.

Comment: Additionaly the `@Autowired` on a single constructor isn't need (as of Spring 4.3) but implied for beans with just a single constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter if you express configuration in XML, properties (yes that is possible, see https://deinum.biz/2018-04-12-on-spring-applicationcontext-and-bean-creation/), java config or annotations. All of those are bean definitions and the relation between those. Spring will have (some kind) of dependency tree.

Beans are constructed in a certain order and destroyed in the reverse order.

The only "wrong" thing in your code is the `demo2.getDemo1()` but in this case shouldn't make any difference as `Demo3` depends on `Demo2 which depends on` Demo1`. Ideally you would write the configuration in the following way

```java
Configuration
class MyConfig {

  @Bean
  public Demo1 demo1(){
    return new demo1()
  }

  @Bean
  public Demo2 demo2(Demo1 demo1){
    return new Demo2(demo1);
  }

  @Bean
  public Demo3 demo3(Demo2 demo2, Demo1 demo1){
   return new Demo3(demo1, demo2);
  }
}
```

This code/config makes it easier for Spring to figure out the interdependencies.

In your case, if you are using Spring Boot **and** have declared those `@Bean` methods you will actually end up with multiple instances of the beans.

Running your sample produces, for me the following output (I added `@PostConstruct` and `@PreDestroy` methods to the classes).

```
2022-09-06 09:03:48.366  INFO 64364 --- [           main] b.d.d.DestructionOrderApplication        : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
biz.deinum.destructionorder.DestructionOrderApplication$Demo1@2fb5fe30 - @PostConstruct
biz.deinum.destructionorder.DestructionOrderApplication$Demo1@389562d6 - @PostConstruct
biz.deinum.destructionorder.DestructionOrderApplication$Demo2@5a101b1c - @PostConstruct
biz.deinum.destructionorder.DestructionOrderApplication$Demo2@2160e52a - @PostConstruct
biz.deinum.destructionorder.DestructionOrderApplication$Demo3@29f0802c - @PostConstruct
biz.deinum.destructionorder.DestructionOrderApplication$Demo3@3a60c416 - @PostConstruct
2022-09-06 09:03:48.559  INFO 64364 --- [           main] b.d.d.DestructionOrderApplication        : Started DestructionOrderApplication in 0.311 seconds (JVM running for 0.552)
biz.deinum.destructionorder.DestructionOrderApplication$Demo3@3a60c416 - @PreDestroy
biz.deinum.destructionorder.DestructionOrderApplication$Demo3@29f0802c - @PreDestroy
biz.deinum.destructionorder.DestructionOrderApplication$Demo2@2160e52a - @PreDestroy
biz.deinum.destructionorder.DestructionOrderApplication$Demo2@5a101b1c - @PreDestroy
biz.deinum.destructionorder.DestructionOrderApplication$Demo1@389562d6 - @PreDestroy
biz.deinum.destructionorder.DestructionOrderApplication$Demo1@2fb5fe30 - @PreDestroy
```

In which you can clearly see the `@PostConstruct` is called in the right order and the `@PreDestroy` in the reverse order. You can also see you have 2 instances. Removing the `@Component` leads to the following output:

```
2022-09-06 09:06:03.520  INFO 64388 --- [           main] b.d.d.DestructionOrderApplication        : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
biz.deinum.destructionorder.DestructionOrderApplication$Demo1@72ab05ed - @PostConstruct
biz.deinum.destructionorder.DestructionOrderApplication$Demo2@27e32fe4 - @PostConstruct
biz.deinum.destructionorder.DestructionOrderApplication$Demo3@c3c4c1c - @PostConstruct
2022-09-06 09:06:03.714  INFO 64388 --- [           main] b.d.d.DestructionOrderApplication        : Started DestructionOrderApplication in 0.32 seconds (JVM running for 0.561)
biz.deinum.destructionorder.DestructionOrderApplication$Demo3@c3c4c1c - @PreDestroy
biz.deinum.destructionorder.DestructionOrderApplication$Demo2@27e32fe4 - @PreDestroy
biz.deinum.destructionorder.DestructionOrderApplication$Demo1@72ab05ed - @PreDestroy
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this explanation. I had a follow up question. What if Demo3 did not depend on Demo2, would demo2.getDemo1() cause a problem in dependency injection?

Comment: It depends. But there is a change that Demo3 is then destroyed before Demo1. But now it depends on `Demo2` because of the call to `demo2()`. So even if `Demo3` wouldn't use `Demo2` physically, it still would have a dependency due to `demo2()`.

Comment: What's exactly wrong about 'demo2.getDemo1()'? Does it affect order of creation or destruction or anything else?

Comment: You shouldn't expose dependencies like that (don't use a getter for dependencies) and you should just wire the dependency and not using a getter from another dependency.